# Method that inputs string outputs color object c#

Tags: c#, object, methods, colors

Im trying to create a method in C# that inputs a string value from a combo box and returns a color object. I've established how to do so with if/else statements in order to compare the string and return the color object but I wanted to decrease the amount of code I'm writing.

```
public static ColorBeingReturned(string TextFromBox)
{
   newcolor = Color.TextFromBox;
   return newcolor;
}
```

I'm sure the code is all incorrect but it gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do. The following is a snippet of what I have with if/else statements.

```
public object ColorBeingReturned(string TextFromBox)
{
    if (TextFromBox == "Red")
      return Color.Red;
    else if (TextFromBox == "Blue")
      return Color.Blue;
    else
      return Color.White;
}
```

Basically instead of having to write all those if else statements I'd rather a few statements so that way if I add additional colors to the list it'll be an easier transition.

Comment: How about using a combobox instead of textbox? You can use predefine values and the code will be simple. Also it will not permit the user to input wrong data.

Comment: `return Color.FromName(TextFromBox);`

Comment: I have a combobox currently. I'm just pulling the text from the combobox in order to do the computation of color.

Comment: How about using the [System.Drawing.Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) enum as the `DataSource` of your ComboBox?

Comment: I thought, that Color is Enum. But it is not, so i am wrong :)

Comment: So am I! Hmmm there is [System.Drawing.KnownColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor.aspx) though

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Color.FromName(TextFromBox)` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname.aspx

You can also use reflection

```
public Color ColorBeingReturned(string TextFromBox)
{
    return (Color)(typeof (Color)
                  .GetProperty(TextFromBox,
                       BindingFlags.Static|
                       BindingFlags.Public|
                       BindingFlags.GetProperty))
                  .GetValue(null, null);
}
```

Comment: this is good unless you're not going to translate the UI into a different language. At that point you need a mapping between the string on UI and a *real* color in your base.

Comment: From ILSpy, `Color.FromName` internally uses a Hashtable. Using reflection should be much slower, and doesn't worth it.

Comment: Yes, I just decompiled and saw that `FromName` works same as reflection with a cache-like mechanism. So, I agree reflection seems useless (:

Answer (score 0):

Add valid color name into your `combo-box`,and use

```
 Color.FromName();
```

Example:

```
Color red = Color.FromName("Red");
```

For fill Combo box with valid color names use:

```
 comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem here is having long `if/else` statements, it's easily resolved by using a dictionary instead.

```
var textVsColor = new Dictionary<string,Color>(); 
textVsColor["Red"] = Color.Red;
textVsColor["Green"] = Color.Green;
...
```

and after instead of long `if/else` just

```
public object ColorBeingReturned(string textFromBox)
{
     var color = dfault(Color);
     textVsColor.TryGetValue(textFromBox, out color); 
     return color;
}
```

This is a good approach for cases where you need to have strings based on a current language of your UI, if you need support multilanguage environment.